# COM object of portable apps

Tags: c#, com, registry

I am aware that we can create a COM object by using

```
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progID);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

But this requires a registry entry of the application of which we are trying to create the COM object.

Is there any possible way of creating a COM object without using windows registry entry, one of the use case can be creating a COM object of portable apps.

Comment: "Registration-Free COM", [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Registration-Free+COM) and MSDN have some reading on the topic.

Comment: What Roman said. Specifically look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542145/create-com-object-from-file-without-regsvr32) which redirects to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx).

Comment: @Roman R and Chase could you please share an example code. Lets say I want to create a COM object of portable apps like eclipse. I looked at the MSDN article but was not able to implement it. Thank you

Comment: @Prabhakar: [this blog post](http://alax.info/blog/1561) discusses a problem with Visual Studio built-in support for registration-free COM. You can skip the text, just locate the part "This simple solution `ComIsolation01`..." which gets you link to source code which implements regfree COM, build it in 32-bits and it will work.

Comment: @Roman R Thank you. Will check and let you know.